# Push state data to an array each time the button is clicked

Tags: reactjs

How do I update the `App` function so the data contained in state is pushed to an array each time the button is pushed?

I've tried using something like `array.push(this.state)` but would appreciate some guidance.

I have found examples using class components but not React hooks.  Does it require something like `useEffect`?

```
import React, { Component, useState, setState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const handleChange = event => setValue(event.target.value);

  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        Input:
        <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
        <input type="button" value="Click Me" onClick={?????}/>
      </label>

    </div>
  );
};


render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Where's the array you're trying to add data to?

Comment: The variable assigned to your state here is `value` so I would imagine you want `array.push(value)`. In functional components there is no `this.state`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a ref for your array so that its content is preserved after an update:

```
const arrayRef = useRef([]);
```

Then you create an onClick function:

```
const onClick = () => {
    arrayRef.current.push(value);
}
```

And call that function from your button:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onClick={onClick}/>
```